# Excel VBA: Defining variable which includes reference to other dynamic variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA and given how much time I've spent trying to resolve the following problem, I would certainly appreciate some help.

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do. In a nutshell, I need to populate Column AA with either one static value of "*" or multiple rows extracted from another column. I keep getting a run-time 1004 error.

```
Sub test()
TotalBG = 2
SelBG = 1

If TotalBG = SelBG Then
Column1RowCount = 2
Column1Value = "*"
Else
Column1RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Q25000").End(xlUp).Row
Column1Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Column1Loop, "Q").Value
End If

k = 2
For Column1Loop = 2 To Column1RowCount
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(k, "AA").Value = Column1Value
k = k + 1
Next Column1Loop

End Sub
```

The line which is giving the error is:

```
Column1Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Column1Loop, "Q").Value
```

I think the reason is that I am referencing a Variable name (Column1Loop) which has not yet been defined. Seems like a Catch 22 (for me, that is) - someone please help!

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You code snippet indeed contains error and will not execute properly because `Column1Loop` is empty pertinent to that particular statement (see the following line from your code snippet):

```
Column1Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Column1Loop, "Q").Value
```

You may modify your code to fix this issue like shown below:

```
 Column1Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Column1RowCount, "Q").Value
```

where `Column1RowCount` would be the value of `Column1Loop` var upon the execution of `For-Next` loop.

Hope this may help.